# How to use omnichannel to route cases from existing queue

Tags: case, email2case, omnichannel

I've a queue in my org which has a bunch of cases. I'd like to distribute the cases automatically to the members using omnichannel. Is that possible or do I need to use a new queue?

Answer (score 0):

In our instance, we do this, but it is a bit complicated. We have a record trigger Flow that looks for Case being created and updated in a particular Queue. When that happens, the Flow then has a subflow that is an OmniChannel Flow that does what we like to call "Down Routing", or basically looping through a set of rules until the Case gets to a Queue where members who are logged in to accept the Case.

The Route Work Action can route to an Agent or to another Queue:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_route_to_specific_agent.htm&type=5

More help can be found in the documentation for how this was done overall:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_use_flow_to_route.htm&type=5

Hopefully that helps!